# The bottom 'pin' of a edge mount HD-BNC connector

Tags: bnc

I find except edge mount SMA connectors, there are also HD-BNC edge connectors, such as [this](https://www.amphenolrf.com/034-5013.html). The recommended PCB land doesn't show the bottom pad.

[image]

For smaller SMA connectors, I usually solder the bottom pin to the bottom of the board. But for this BNC edge connector, it is a little 'bigger'. So, I wonder what's the pron's and con's to solder the bottom pad, except for making the connection more robust?

Comment: 1) The gap is a strange size, at just under 3/32", so you'd need a PCB that fits. 2) That's one heck of a thermal mass...

Comment: Yes, this connector is target for 0.080 inch board thickness. And there are other models target different board thickness.

Comment: Will it have some effect to the electrical characteristic, such impedance, etc?

Comment: Note that connector is not BNC, it's "HD-BNC" which is small and proprietary.

Comment: Yes, it's a smaller "HD-BNC".